# Multiprocessing vs Multi threading

Tags: multithreading, multiprocessing

Let's say I have 2 cores . Then I can run 2 processes one on each correct.

Threads are internal to processes.So in multi threading how can a thread be executed on a different core.

Apparently I read somewhere in multi threading if one thread is executed on a different core then it will be slower due to context switch.

But I still don't understand if a process runs on a core and all threads are specific to one process then how can a thread of a same process gets executed on a different core.

Please help me here.

Comment: The OS only concerns itself with scheduling threads (tasks) to run on CPU cores. The fact that they are from different processes means very little. Threads from the same process simply share the same virtual address space. You really need a good book on the topic. This  is off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

**Process** is an instance of a computer program that is being executed. It contains the program code and its current activity.
Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_(computing))

**Thread** is the smallest sequence of programmed instructions that can be managed independently by a scheduler.
Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread_(computing))

Simply put, process is a virtual set of resources (program code, data, stack, heap), while thread is what is being executed by CPU core. It means every process has at least one thread, but might as well have many.

> Apparently I read somewhere in multi threading if one thread is executed on a different core then it will be slower due to context switch.

**Context switch** is the process of storing the state of a process or of a thread. This allows multiple processes to share a single CPU, and is an essential feature of a multitasking operating system.
Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context_switch)

Simply put, context switch happens when there are more active treads than active CPUs. It might happen as well when we have just one process and one thread.